How do I include the length (time) column of a file when I "Get Data from Folder" in Excel?
When I perform a Get Data > From File > From Folder in Excel, the following columns are extracted -
Content, Name, Extension, Date accessed, Date modified, Date created, Attributes, and Folder Path.
How can I include Length, in the case of a folder containing media files?
None of my searching has yielded any information on how to change the information imported into Excel using this method.
Thanks in advance.

It is one of the Attributes.
Add a Custom column with the name Length

and the formula:
=[Attributes][Size]



To include the Length (or size) of media files when importing folder data into Excel, you can use Power Query (Get & Transform Data) to customize your data extraction. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:

Open Power Query Editor:

Open Excel and go to the Data tab.
Select Get Data > From File > From Folder.


Choose the Folder:

In the dialog that appears, browse and select the folder containing your media files.
Click OK.


Load Folder Data:

In the next dialog, click Combine & Load > Combine & Load To….
In the Import Data dialog, select Only Create Connection and click OK.


Open Power Query Editor:

In the Queries & Connections pane, right-click on the newly created query and select Edit.
The Power Query Editor will open, showing the folder's content.


Add File Size Column:

In the Power Query Editor, click on the Add Column tab.
Select Custom Column.
In the Custom Column dialog, enter the following details:

New column name: Length
Custom column formula: File.Contents([Folder Path] & [Name])


Click OK.


Transform the Data:

After adding the Length column, you will see binary content in this column.
Click on the small icon at the top-right of the Length column (it looks like a downward arrow).
Choose to Extract Size from the binary column.
This will create a new column with the size of each file in bytes.


Remove Unnecessary Columns:

If there are any columns you do not need, right-click on the column headers and select Remove.


Load the Data into Excel:

Once your data is in the desired format, click Close & Load in the Home tab of Power Query Editor.
Your data, including the file size, will now be loaded into Excel.



By following these steps, you should be able to import folder data into Excel with the Length (size) of the media files included.
